# How much power draws a system like this idling in BIOS?

Tags: untagged

Let's assume a generic system like this:

- Two modern multi-core CPUs, like a Xeon Dual Core
- 2x 7120M, 3.00 GHz, 95 W power dissipation each, according to Wikipedia
- 2x 835Watt PSU (redundant)
- 8GB RAM
- 4 HDDs
- no video

What would such a system approximately draw when I switch it on and send it to BIOS? Idling...

Comment: it draws whatever it draws and the only way to know what that is would be to use the meter Chris suggests below. And what it draws while "idle" in the BIOS setup screens has no relation to what it will draw during use by the way, if you're trying to use one figure to get to the other.

Comment: My ISP uses BIOS idling as their benchmark for the average system. Nice ISP ;) - that's why. I was hoping for some rough rule of thumb figures, like: the 95W Xeon idles in ~ 15W, 4 drives à 8W, PSU @ 30% is +5W, RAM is 5W per GB. Some common figures... BEFORE I bid on hardware. (Sorry if I'm annoying everyone)

Comment: You can't have a "rule of thumb" because each machine is so different I'm afraid. I guess they're doing it that way because it's consistent...

Answer (score 7):

For $20 you could [get a meter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0032JRGZ8) that would give you the data you seek.

Comment: He doesn't have the system yet AFAIK, so this isn't an option.